# Infinite sequence of regular languages over fixed finite alphabet

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages

Construct an infinite sequence of regular languages $L_1, L_2 , \ldots$, over the same fixed finite alphabet, such that for every $i ≥ 1$, $L_i ⊇ L_{i+1}$ and $|L_i \setminus L_{i+1} | = ∞$.

Comment: I mean is there any formal way to do this particular question ??

Comment: @Shaull I wanted a more specific(formal) method to do this problem ?? To which i m not getting any clue

Comment: @Yuval Filmus's answer is perfectly formal (assuming you correctly continue it). I believe you are struggling because you want a constructive procedure that would allow you to find an answer. Well - there isn't one. Not all problems have a constructive solution.

Comment: If you mean you wanted a constructive way of finding an answer to such a question, that is precisely what I tried to give you by starting from what one may consider a simpler problem. Whatever you construct is constructed from simpler bricks. But Yuval Filmus' answer is perfectly formal ... Everything you do requires a little bit of inventiveness somewhere. When you apply recipees, it is just that someone invented it for you.

Comment: @YashPatel Added some explanation regarding an analysis to find out how to create solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start with a problem that seems intuitively easier, and then use closure properties of regular sets. Here is an example.

Take any infinite sequence of infinite and disjoint regular sets
$R_i, i=1,2, \ldots$. Start with $L_1=\Sigma^*$, and build the
sequence $L_{i+1}=L_i\setminus R_i$.

For example, with $\Sigma=\{0,1\}$ you can take $R_i=0^i1^*$

**Added after comments to the initial question: analysis and synthesis**

Since you want some form of reasonning to find a solution. Here is a
possible analysis of the problem, from which one then get in reverse the
construction technique suggested.

Assume that the sequence $L_1,L_2,\ldots$ satisfies the given
considitons for an answer. Then consider the sequence $R_1, R_2,\ldots$ defined by
$R_i=L_i\setminus L_{i+1}$. The conditions on the $L_i$ sequence imply
that each $R_i$ is an infinite set, and it is regular since regular
set are closed under set difference. They are also all disjoint, since
by construction, no $R_i$ can contains elements from $R_j$ for any
$j\leq i$ (out of two such sets, there is always one with a smaller
index).

They are also all contained in $L_1$ by construction.

Given that any solution has these properties, you may wonder whether
these are sufficient to obtain the desired decreasing sequence you
wanted. This may be useful since defining an infinite sequence of
disjoint infinite regular sets $R_i$ is rather easy.

Using closure properties of regular sets, it is easily proved that
indeed such a construction, as given at the beginning of my answer,
will work to answer the question, provided that each $R_i$ is included
in $L_1$.

But choosing $L_1=\Sigma^*$ I make certain that that is the case.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: One option is to take $L_1 = 0^*$, $L_2 = (00)^*$, and so on. There are many others.

Comment: I thought of this already but can u suggest any other alternative(i.e. formal method) to so this problem ??

Comment: This is a formal method. It's a formal proof. It answers your question. What more do you need?

Comment: I was struggling because I wanted a constructive procedure to find answer to my question...but it is not needed as babou has provided it below !! :) Anyways thank you for ur time !! :)